# ONLY NULL VALUE IS INSERTED IN TO MYSQL DATABASE

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i have simple program in jsp. i try to do connection with mysql database using java class and it well connected. the problem is WHEN I TRIED TO INSERT DATA IN TO DATABASE, ONLY "NULL" VALUE IS INSRTED.

```
package DataAccessObject;

import java.sql.*;


/**
 *
 * @author user
 */

public class DBConnection {

private static Connection conn=null;

private  static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/selftest";

//private  static   String dbName = "selftest";

private  static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

private  static String userName = "root"; 

private  static String password = "123456";

public static Connection getConnection(){

        try{
            if(conn != null){//
                return conn;//if the object already exist use it
            }
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("meche connect hone");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

AND THE OTHER CLASS IS

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class selftestDB {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        selftestDB sd=new selftestDB();
    }
    private Statement stmt = null;

    private Connection conn = null;

    public selftestDB()
    {
        try {
            conn = DBConnection.getConnection();//conection lemefter since its possible to create frm any where
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("hay connection create honual.....enkuan des yaleh");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("bra izi newu chigiru");

        }
    }
    public boolean saveacc(accountDO createacc){
    {
        if(stmt==null)

          return false;
    }

     try
    {
        System.out.println("datah save honual");
       String sql="insert into account(username,password,usertype) values('" 

                    + createacc.getusername() + "','"
                    + createacc.getpassword() + "','"
                    + createacc.getusertype() + "')";

        /*String sql="insert into account values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        accountDO acd=new accountDO();
        String username=acd.getusername();
        String password=acd.getpassword();
        String usertype=acd.getusertype();
          ps.setString(1, username);
          ps.setString(2, password);
          ps.setString(3, usertype);
          ps.executeUpdate();
          ps.close();
         * int result=ps.executeUpdate();
         */
          int result=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


          if(result>0)
          {
              return true;

          }

    else
          {
              return false;
          }
    } 

     catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }

}

}
```

please help me why "null value " is inserted[username=null password=null and usertype=null]

###remember to, i have one other class to "set" and "get" data. and one JSP page to process the request from the "form"

Comment: SHOUTING in title is not best way when asking for help.

Comment: THIS IS WAY TOO MUCH CODE FOR ME TO READ. POST A SSCCE IF YOU WANT SOME HELP OKAY!!!!

Comment: [capslock is cruise control for cool](http://maddox.xmission.com/hatemail.cgi?p=1#CAPSLOCK)

Comment: perhaps your createacc obj has null values?

Answer (score 1):

there are couple things possible here:

Either the data type of the variables do not match. (what you are trying to insert through sql query should be in correspondence with the column's data type)

or the name of the variables "username,password,usertype" cannot find a mapping to your database columns.

Comment: I dont know why my answer is been downvoted. I happened to had the same issue and thats what I figured out. Initially I thought he did a mistake while making a connection and thats why I answered with that. then I edited my answer to make the best sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I got to reply like this,

Did you try before running your

```
int result=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Try

```
System.out.printl(createacc.getusername());
System.out.printl(createacc.getpassword());
System.out.printl(createacc.getusertype());
```

See what you get here... Maybe there is no string values

I'm quite sure your get methods return NULLS.. or possible of a different datatype. You also might need to .toString()

Comment: yaa, dear its NULL value in the getmethod. but i try to make the flow logical, here the below code that set and get the data

Comment: and i have userform.jsp for user form and one other jsp file to process it.

Answer (score 0):

You never seem to call the saveAcc method in your code. When you do (add) such code, be sure you initialize the parameter, so that it has values you expect to add to the database.